# Java: toLowercase messes up the unicode symbols

Tags: java, unicode, character

My Code:

```
// Read the turkish file contents to the variable currentLine
currentLine = currentLine+"\n\n"+currentLine.toLowerCase();
// Write the contents to a new file
```

Output:

Yukar mavi gök asağı yağız yer yaratıldık iki arası in oğlu yaratılmış İnsan oğulları üzer ecdadı Bumın haka İste haka tah oturmuş oturarak Türk millet ülke türe idar edivermiş tanz edivermis Dört taraf hep düşman imiş Asker sevk edip dört taraf kavmi hep itaa altına almış hep muti kılmış Başlı baş eğdirmiş dizli diz çöktürmüş

﻿yukar mavi g�k asa��� ya���z yer yarat�ld�k iki aras� in o��lu yarat�lm��� �nsan o��ullar� �zer ecdad� bum�n haka �ste haka tah oturmu�� oturarak t�rk millet �lke t�re idar edivermi�� tanz edivermis d�rt taraf hep d���man imi�� asker sevk edip d�rt taraf kavmi hep itaa alt�na alm��� hep muti k�lm��� ba��l� ba�� e��dirmi�� dizli diz ��kt�rm���

I tried toLowercase(Locale.getDefault()) and toLowercase(Locale.ROOT). I still get the same output.
Why is the function returning invalid symbols?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you specified a wrong encoding when reading (or writing) the data? Try to put explicit UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: @Thilo I *think* UTF-16 is required here.

Comment: But then how is it that half of the file has proper encoding? The first line is having the right symbols. The second line (that was returned by the tolowercase() function) has invalid symbols.

Comment: The first line has the same symbols that you read in. There was no computation done. That can work even with the wrong encoding. For lowercase transformation, Java needs to know the proper encoding.

Comment: @Thilo That was right! Now the strange characters have vanished. New '?' characters appeared all over the output, but I fixed that by using UTF-8 OutputStreamWriter for BufferedWriter. Please post it as the answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Aswin: Why do you need to lowercase the text in the first place? Typically, you should instead just normalize the Unicode text and then use a locale-aware case insensitive comparison later.

Comment: @DanielPryden I'm not doing comparison. I convert the text to lowercase as a part of preprocessing for stemming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem comes from not declaring the character encoding when reading and writing the file. In this case Java assumes your platform default character set, which may not be appropriate.

If unsure, use UTF-8, that also covers Turkish (of course, it needs to match the file you actually have to read from).

You may also have to specify the Turkish Locale when calling toLowercase, since the exact rules may depend on the language this text is in (I'm not familiar with Turkish, it may just work already with the defaults).

> But then how is it that half of the file has proper encoding?

The first line has the same symbols that you read in. There was no computation done. That can work even with the wrong encoding. For lowercase transformation, Java needs to know the proper encoding.

> Now the strange characters have vanished. New '?' characters appeared all over the output

Half-way there. Now that you specified the input character set on your Reader, Java can understand your Turkish characters. But it still cannot output them, so it replaces them with "?". You also need to set the output character set on your Writer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to pass local info in `toString()` method. [Here is an example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28java.util.Locale%29) in Java official documentation with Turkish as an example. Without Locale info, the `toString()` method will use default locale.

Here is how to create Turkish Locale,

```
Locale trlocale= Locale.forLanguageTag("tr_TR");
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this and still the output is messed up.  

Locale trLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR");
currentLine = currentLine+"\n"+currentLine.toLowerCase(trLocale);

Comment: Please don't use dash in `tr-TR`, use underscore. I corrected the post.

Comment: Specifying that doesn't seem to change anything in the string. Thanks for trying.